# I need to extract email addresses from yahoo full headers and need help matching them

Tags: php

I have several thousand emails saved in a directory. These emails are opened with file_get_contents. I need to match all reply-to: emails from these headers. How do I match them?

Comment: Jim, meet John, who asked an eerily similar question 30 minutes ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828397/how-to-extract-emails-from-full-headers

Comment: Hmm.. Thanks for the thread. I tried all of those suggestions but they dont help.

Answer (score 1):

From my answer on the eerily similar question - I agree that parsing e-mails (which I've had to do) is surprisingly painful:

---

Some mail *sending* libraries can parse raw email, while [not that well documented](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/Zend_Mail/Zend_Mail_Message.html) Zend_Mail should be able to do that by passing your raw email to a Zend_Mail_Message object. *(Note: [Reading mailboxes is well documented](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.read.html), from what I've seen,  reading a raw message isn't.)*

```
$message = new Zend_Mail_Message(array(), $filename);
$sender = $message->getHeader('Reply-To');
```

If all you need is the sender, then a good RegEx would be better to use, however, if you will be testing other headers/manipulating the body/mime parts, then using a library will be worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing e-mails is going to be a pain *(I've seen people try to parse e-mails, and always fail in some cases they didn't think about... )* ; I would nto go with parsing them by hand, and possibly re-inventing the wheel...

A solution I would prefer is using some existing library, that parses e-mails and extract data from them, like, for instance, [`Zend_Mail`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.read.html).

If you really cannot (or don't want to) use any existing library, I suppose a couple of regex might do the trick... But don't forget to read the RFC about e-mails : it will help you identify some cases you wouldn't think about...

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to really create a complicated regex to parse emails. Use PHP's string methods to find where the word "reply-to" is, then get the next word after it and check for "@". These should be your emails. Leave the "checking" of valid email to the MTA servers when you send them out.